# Are the blue/red colors of scattering visible only Because of the large size of the atmosphere?

Tags: optics, visible-light, scattering, atmospheric-science

hypothetically, would you be able to see the scatter of color if you shine a light on $N_2$/$O_2$ particles in a small model of the atmosphere? is it possible on an entirely shrunken scale or is there a certain distance of parties the light has to reach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the large distances involved are extremely important. A scale model of the atmosphere would appear transparent, as you would expect.

At a wavelength of $532~\rm nm$ (green light), a photon travels a mean distance of around $80~\rm km$ in air, so scales smaller than that won't exhibit much scattering effects at all.